# When I boot up Ubuntu, nothing is loading. No file icons or my profile picture

Tags: icons

I recently installed Ubuntu.
When I boot up Ubuntu I see the log in screen. My picture is grayed out and the background is blue. Text still appears though. When I enter my password and press enter, I am brought to my desktop but no file icons appear. The text is still there. Command line does not work. I am on a very slow computer. Do I just need to wait for the files to load?

Comment: *I am on a very slow computer. Do I just need to wait for the files to load?* Possibly yes, you do, but if it's that old/underpowered then standard Ubuntu isn't recommended. Try Lubuntu or Xubuntu instead (currently only for 64-bit).

Comment: When I first installed it, everything was working perfectly fine. Then I restarted it and all my file icons disappeared.

Comment: Try adding a test user account and log in to the newly created test account. If the test account displays everything correctly, it may be that you have lost the profile settings. This link https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/10/how-to-reset-ubuntu-desktop-to-default may be useful to reset your account settings to default values